# In Unity can I modify at runtime the mesh of a terrain created using the terrain editing tools so that I can 'dig' a hole?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development, unity3d-terrain

I am new to Unity and would like to be able to emulate the idea of 'digging' a hole in the 'earth' with a spade, at runtime and have the terrain slightly ahead of my camera lower slightly, then move that dug 'earth' into a pile somewhere next to the hole.

I have created a terrain using the preview terrain tools and now want to alter it at runtime a little like you see in this part of this video : https://youtu.be/l_2uGpjBMl4?t=2970

I want to be able to make a small 'dig' into my environment, just like a spade making a hole in the earth, and that state to then be something I can persist.

I then want to be able to move the 'dig' volume, i.e the 'earth' onto somewhere else in the terrain - literally imagine what happens when you dig a hole.

If I want to follow this guy's video, he is generating his terrain, and I am not sure how to apply his logic, because I would likely want to shoot a raycast from my camera, and where it intersects with the world, then alter the 'mesh' of my painted terrain, and then add to a 'pile' of earth somewhere else. I am not sure about just doing the piles of earth with just changing the height of the terrain, because there would need to be a volume associated with the 'earth' you have dug, so it's more of a object, than a terrain if you see what I mean.

I realise this is a bit of a braindump, but I am looking for direction and have done research these are the questions I would like answered, I want this to be a sounding board for whether my thoughts are on the right path, and if not, what is an optimal course for learning some techniques for achieving this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`Terrain.terrainData`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Terrain-terrainData.html) which contains the [`GetHeights`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TerrainData.GetHeights.html) and  [`SetHeightsDelayLOD`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TerrainData.SetHeightsDelayLOD.html) methods. [`SetHeights`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TerrainData.SetHeights.html) is also available, but is not as efficient. Check the documentation to see how they work!